# UserAgent is not detect real device when I opened web on Chrome mobile mode, userAgent said it's mobile

Tags: angular, user-agent

when I opened web on Chrome mobile mode, userAgent said it's mobile but I wanna know what is the real device used.

Comment: You can check [Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: what does it have to do with angular?